# Is there such a thing as a "medium"-copy? Or: how to finely control "depth" of copy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, deep-copy

I have a dictionary. The dictionary keys are integers, and the values are ***lists of objects***.

I want to be able to copy the dictionary in such a way that I refer back to the exact **same objects**, but *different lists*.

When I use a normal copy -- either dict.copy() or copy.copy(dict) -- any changes I make to the lists in the copied dictionary also change the original dictionary's lists.

However, when I use copy.deepcopy(dict), it goes all the way and makes new objects, so that I can't, e.g., use the original dictionary's lists as a "to-do" as I remove particular objects from the copied dictionary's lists, or make any other kind of changes to the copied dictionary's lists that require comparison to the original objects.

The documentation on the "copy" module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) doesn't seem to mention any kind of in-between option, or some way to adjust the deep-ness.

Does such an option or function or whatnot exist? If not, am I just thinking about the problem from the wrong angle? For example, I imagine that I might be able to achieve the desired behavior if I iterated through the dictionary and manually "copied" things that way (but this seems rather long-winded!?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just implement your own version of "medium"-copy:

```
import copy


def mediumcopy(value):
    return dict(
        (key, copy.copy(val))
        for key, val in value.iteritems())

z = {'a': [[1], [2]]}
zcopy = mediumcopy(z)
assert id(z) != id(zcopy)  # True
assert id(z['a']) != id(zcopy['a'])  # True
assert id(z['a'][0]) == id(zcopy['a'][0])  # True
```

Python 3 version:

```
def mediumcopy(value):
    return {key: list(val)  # you can still use copy.copy here
            for key, val in value.items()}

z = {'a': [[1], [2]]}
zcopy = mediumcopy(z)
assert id(z) != id(zcopy)  # True
assert id(z['a']) != id(zcopy['a'])  # True
assert id(z['a'][0]) == id(zcopy['a'][0])  # True
```

Comment: You beat me by about two minutes.  I was just typing up an equivalent response.  :-)

Comment: @Prune :) :) :)

Comment: That makes sense! And I would write another version (or add in an "if" to the function or something, but effectively the same amount of work) for different "depths", I suppose? (I only had one kind of "depth" in my personal project, with one exception, so it wasn't a issue, but I can imagine.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the copy of `list`s (which are value to your `dict`). You may do that even without `copy.copy()`.

```
new_list = list(old_list)
```

will create the `copy` of `old_list` with the same content, and store it as `new_list`.

Hence, your *dict comprehension* expression to create new dict should be as:

```
new_dict = {k: list(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

where `my_dict` is your original dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `dict` that implements the `__deepcopy__` method as a shallow copy, and use that subclass (rather than native `dict`) at the level at which you want deepcopying to stop.